# Different text direction for different lines of a textView

Tags: android, localization, right-to-left

In my multi-lingual app, I handle text direction of a TextView based on the first character to be either RTL or LTR. Then the gravity would be set accordingly, too.
What I want is different lines of a single TextView to have their own text directions and/or gravity.

[image: Multi directional Text View]

How should I achieve this?

**Update:**

As *babadaba* answered, *TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL* does exactly like what I want. Here is the explanation in comments:

> Text direction is using "any-RTL" algorithm. The paragraph direction is RTL if it contains any strong RTL character, otherwise it is LTR if it contains any strong LTR characters. If there are neither, the paragraph direction is the view's resolved layout direction.

Now, the question is how to implement ANY_RTL in API levels older that 17 ?

Answer (score 2):

Create your Textview like this:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="مرحبا \n Hello \n مرحبا"
    android:textDirection="anyRtl" />
```

It should check for each line if it has strong Arabic or Non-Arabic letters and format the line accordingly.

For older API Levels, you can try manually adding ‏‏the Unicode \u200F to your lines where you want RTL layout.

Comment: It works. The only point is that the attribute textDirection is only used in API level 17+. any workaround for older ones?

Comment: Check my edit, I provided a solution for older API Levels. Try that and report if it works for you :)

Comment: It's not that I know which line should to be RTL or not! It's completely based on the content provided by users. It may be completely in an LTR language or fully in RTL. Or it might be a combination of both in separate lines, which is our problem here...

Comment: How does the user provide the content? Via an EditText? If you can tell me how you get the String I may can write a little function which checks the String line by line and adds the unicode.

Comment: You can consider the string as the input parameter of your function.