# different text direction for different lines of a textfield in flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield, text-direction

I'm making a chat app with flutter
Can anyone help me to use different text direction on each line of textfield or suggest some library for rtl and ltr?

I tried to detect text direction in textfield by intl package it works just for one line of text and set direction of textfield based on first line of text

**I need something like textView in telegram app that change direction of text according to each line of text**

[image: what i need]

I need exactly something like this
[question different-text-direction-for-different-lines-of-a-textview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38159204/different-text-direction-for-different-lines-of-a-textview)

This package didn't help me [auto_direction package]  (
https://pub.dev/packages/auto_direction)